# PHP Nested While Loops with Different MySQL Querys

Tags: php, mysql

I have a nested while loop running a separate SQL query from the primary loop to display an indicator that a field catagory was not completely filled out (there is verification to prevent this but the powers that be still want this included) by changing the value of a variable.  This always evaluates to false despite Uname coming from the same table for both loops.  When break is added it evaluates the first instance as true, then continues to evaluate false for subsequent loops through the first loop despite there still being rows that should evaluate true.

```
while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($exec2)) {
            // echo var_dump($row2);
            if ($row['Uname'] == $row2['Uname']) {
                $em_con="<span style='color:red;'>Need</span>";

            }
            else {
                $em_con="why?";

            }
// break 1;         
}
```

Additional Code:

First Loop Query:

```
$sql="SELECT Uname,name,datesav,handak,coe,(ISNULL(em_med) OR (CHAR_LENGTH(em_med)<1)) as em FROM hr_forms.emp_info ORDER BY name";
```

Second Loop Query:

```
$sql2="SELECT Uname FROM hr_forms.emp_info 
       WHERE (((em_nm1 is NULL OR em_nm1 = '') OR
       ((em_hmphone_nm1 is NULL OR em_hmphone_nm1 = '') AND (em_celphone_nm1 is NULL OR em_celphone_nm1 = ''))) AND

       ((em_nm2 is NULL OR em_nm2 = '') OR
       ((em_hmphone_nm2 is NULL OR em_hmphone_nm2 = '') AND (em_celphone_nm2 is NULL OR em_celphone_nm2 = ''))) AND

       ((em_nm3 is NULL OR em_nm3 = '') OR
       ((em_hmphone_nm3 is NULL OR em_hmphone_nm3 = '') AND (em_celphone_nm3 is NULL OR em_celphone_nm3 = ''))) AND

       ((em_nm4 is NULL OR em_nm4 = '') OR
       ((em_hmphone_nm4 is NULL OR em_hmphone_nm4 = '') AND (em_celphone_nm4 is NULL OR em_celphone_nm4 = ''))))";
```

First Loop:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec)) {

   //code building page with database values //

     while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($exec2)) {
            // echo var_dump($row2);
            if ($row['Uname'] == $row2['Uname']) {
                $em_con="<span style='color:red;'>Need</span>";

            }
            else {
                $em_con="why?";

            }
     // break 1;            
     }
    echo"   <td class='center'>$em_con</td>"; // variable in question
    //remaining echo'd html
 }
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Add all the nested loops and the queries please.

Comment: Not sure if that is what you want to ask, but if you reexecute `mysql_fetch_array` whithout reexecuting the query, it doesn't yield the array you want again (not sure about it though) and therefore it always compares your first array to an empty one.

Comment: Where are you executing $sql2?  If outside the first while loop, the nested while loop will only run once.  (see @Sebb comment).

Comment: Thank you Sebb, Pagerange, that fixed it you saved me from losing my mind.